# How to get message body attribute on blob input?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function with a service bus trigger:

```
  public static async Task<string> Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("sometopic", "somesub",Connection = "SbConnectionString")] Message message,
        [Blob("files/upload/{userId}/user.jpeg", FileAccess.Write)] Stream file,
        string userId,
        ILogger log)
    {

          ..some code
    }
```

But I´m getting this error:

> The 'Run' function is in error:
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'ResponseTopicEmail'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve
>   binding parameter 'userId'. Binding expressions must map to
>   either a value provided by the trigger or a property of the value the
>   trigger is bound to, or must be a system binding expression (e.g.
>   sys.randguid, sys.utcnow, etc.).

Is there a way to get some property from the `Message` body and use it to get the blob output?

Comment: userId is a property of Message?

Comment: Payload expressions might not currently work with ServiceBus triggers. There is an open issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47091

Comment: @BryanLewis userId is a property of the payload of the body of the Message.

Comment: @gog, if the issue that basvo points is correct, then that is probably your problem.  I've done payload binding with Queue triggers a lot, but never with Service Bus.  Also, why do you have a separate "string userId" param?  That param isn't using a valid binding.

Comment: @BryanLewis actually I was using a custom object so the function runtime was able to deserealize and "understand" this `userId` param and get the correct blob. But I needed to change to the Message object which is the default object of the service bus messages.